# ArithmeticException with Mixed Fractions calculator

Tags: java, exception

This program correctly calculates mixed fractions. I want the while loop to terminate once I enter two zeros. However, when I entered two zeros separated by a space, I get " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero at MixedFractions.main etc. I just want the user to not be able to input a value for a and be once they enter 0 for both variables. Thank you

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class MixedFractions  {
public static void main (String [] args)
{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = scan.nextInt(); int b = scan.nextInt();
    int c = Math.abs(a / b);
    int d = c * b;
    int e = c * b;
    int f = a - e;
    while ( a != 0 && b!= 0)
    {


        if(c == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(c + " " + a  + " / " + b);
        }
        else if(d == a)
        {
            a = 0;
            System.out.println(c + " " + a  + " / " + b);

        }
        else if( c != a)
        {
             e = c * b;
             f = a - e;
            System.out.println(c + " " + f  + " / " + b);
        }
        a = scan.nextInt(); b = scan.nextInt();
        c = Math.abs(a/b);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Before `int c = Math.abs(a / b);` add what you want : `if ( a == 0 && b == 0 ) { ... BOOM ... }`.

Comment: You should consider catching `ArithmeticException` or that error would still occur at other times when `0` is entered for `b`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = scan.nextInt(); 
    int b = scan.nextInt();
    while ( a != 0 && b!= 0) {
        int c = Math.abs(a / b);
        int d = c * b;
        if(c == 0) {
            System.out.println(c + " " + a  + " / " + b);
        } else if(d == a) {
            a = 0;
            System.out.println(c + " " + a  + " / " + b);
        } else if( c != a) {
            int e = c * b;
            int f = a - e;
            System.out.println(c + " " + f  + " / " + b);
        }
        a = scan.nextInt(); 
        b = scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```